# f"MySQL Connector/Python C Extension not available ({exc})" SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm making a program that requires MySQL connection. I'm using jupyter notebook & made the connection with this syntax :

```
!pip install mysql-connector-python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

#change the value of host, user, password, database
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  password="ayyi",
  database="coba"
)
```

It worked smoothly with python version 3.9.13
However, I need to make my program works for python version 2.7. When running the code in this version, I got this following error :

```
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\sayyi\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (8.0.32)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<=3.20.3,>=3.11.0 in c:\users\sayyi\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (3.18.0)
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
  File "C:\Users\sayyi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 82
    f"MySQL Connector/Python C Extension not available ({exc})"
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've been looking for alternatives & found some suggestions to try, such as : importing _mysql_connector module. But none of the suggestions I found seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

```
pip install mysql-connector-python==8.0.23
```

8.0.24 doesn't support python 2.7.